# Why is 'theDate' printing out a decade off?

Tags: r, date

Writing code to modify business days according to weekends and Federal holidays, but for some reason my 'theDate' variable keeps printing out a decade off even though it's stored as the proper date over in my RStudio environment.

I've tried a variety of date formatting, but I can't seem to wrap my head around what's causing this issue.

```
library(date)
library(tis)
start <- as.Date("2019-01-01", '%Y-%d-%m')
end   <- as.Date("2020-01-01", '%Y-%d-%m')

theDate <- start

while (theDate <= end)
{
  if(weekdays(theDate) == 'Saturday'){
    ModDate <- theDate - 1
  } else if(weekdays(theDate) == 'Sunday'){
      ModDate <- theDate - 2
  } else if(weekdays(theDate) == 'Monday'){
      ModDate <- theDate - 3
  } else {
      ModDate <- theDate - 1
  }
  if(isHoliday(ModDate) == TRUE){
    ModDate <- previousBusinessDay(ModDate)
  } else {
  }
  FormatDate <- format(ModDate, '%m/%d/%Y')
  cat("\nBaseDate: ", date.mmddyyyy(theDate), "\tMBP Date: ",
 FormatDate)
  theDate <- theDate + 1                    
}
```

Expect something along these lines:

1. BaseDate: 12/31/2018    MBP Date: 12/31/2018
2. BaseDate:  1/1/2019     MBP Date:  12/31/2018
3. BaseDate:  1/2/2019     MBP Date:  01/02/2019

But keep getting this:

1. BaseDate:  12/31/2008   MBP Date:  12/31/2018
2. BaseDate:  1/1/2009     MBP Date:  12/31/2018
3. BaseDate:  1/2/2009     MBP Date:  01/02/2019

Comment: Where are the functions `isHoliday`, `previousBusinessDay`, and `date.mmddyyyy` coming from?

Comment: Whoops sorry! ````isHoliday```` and ````previousBusinessDay```` come from ````tis```` and ````date.mmddyyy```` comes from ````date````

Comment: `date.mmddyyyy` isn't doing what you want it to. See `date.mmddyyyy(start)`

Comment: You probably just want: `cat("\nBaseDate: ", format(theDate, '%m/%d/%Y'), "\tMBP Date: ", FormatDate)`

Comment: If I remove ````date.mmddyyy```` I get the Julian numbers outputted but they are still a decade off.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

`date.mmddyyyy(theDate)` doesn't change the format of a date to `mm/dd/yyyy`

From `date.mmddyyy` help:

> Given a vector of Julian dates, this returns them in the form “10/11/1989”, “28/7/1854”, etc.

`date.mmddyyyy(theDate)` is trying to parse an already parsed date, hence strange result that's off by a decade.

We can fix it by using `format` instead:

```
cat("\nBaseDate: ", format(theDate, '%m/%d/%Y'), "\tMBP Date: ", FormatDate)

BaseDate:  01/01/2019   MBP Date:  12/31/2018
BaseDate:  01/02/2019   MBP Date:  12/31/2018
BaseDate:  01/03/2019   MBP Date:  01/02/2019
BaseDate:  01/04/2019   MBP Date:  01/03/2019
BaseDate:  01/05/2019   MBP Date:  01/04/2019
BaseDate:  01/06/2019   MBP Date:  01/04/2019
```